# Speech visualization and Speech to Text in Flask Python

Tags: flask, visualization, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to make a flask app where i want to record audio from user and I want to visualize audio in real time and generate a speech to text. I am able to generate text from audio but how do I add speech visualization to this?

Here is my code.

app.py -

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session, flash, jsonify
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required, login_user, logout_user, current_user
from datetime import timedelta
from flask_wtf import CSRFProtect
import speech_recognition as sr
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

app = Flask(__name__)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)

app.config.update(
    DEBUG = True,
    SECRET_KEY = 'SECRETKEY')

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = "login"
login_manager.login_message = u"Login to access this page." 

class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, userId):
        self.userId = userId

    def get_id(self):
        return self.userId

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

@app.route('/record', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def record():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        global score
        if request.form["action"] == 'Record':
            r = sr.Recognizer()
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                r.pause_threshold = 2
                r.energy_threshold = 300
                audio = r.listen(source, timeout=5, phrase_time_limit=15)
                try:
                    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                    original = format_rhyme("This is an apple")
                    sung = format_rhyme(text)
                    accuracy = similar(original, sung)
                    return render_template('record.html', sung=sung, accuracy=accuracy)
                except:
                    text = "Sorry could not recognize what you said"
                    return render_template('record.html',  text=text)
    return render_template("record.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is my Index.html -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/Main.css')}}">
</head>

<body>
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    <p><a href="/home">Home</a> | <a href="/record">Record</a> | <a href="/profile">Profile</a> | <a href="/logout">Logout</a></p>
    {% endif %}
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

This is my record.html -

```
<!doctype html>
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block title %} Rhyme {% endblock %}
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/recorder.js') }}"></script>
{% block content %}
    
<form method="POST">
            
            <button type=" submit" name="action" value="Record" ><span>
             <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value = "{{ csrf_token() }}" /> 
              </span> Record</button>
            {% if sung %}
            <p>This is what you said: {{ sung }}</p>
            <p>Accuracy: {{ accuracy }}</p>
        {% endif %}

        {% if text %}
            {{ text }}
        {% endif %}
           
        </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I am expecting real time audio visualization and speech to text conversion of the recorded audio using SpeechRecognition

Comment: that way you are accessing `Microphone` on server. however you need to grab microphone input on client side, then pass it to flask server for further processing.

Comment: For visualisation of speech, consider using the `sox` library - https://pypi.org/project/sox/

Comment: @marmeladze How do I do that?